# What is the difference between "resign" and "surrender"?

Tags: differences

Why do you **resign** a game of chess, but **surrender** a war?

Comment: Why? Because that's how English expresses those actions. There is no secret formula that will help you figure out when to use *resign*, *surrender*, *capitulate*, *give up*, *give over*, *give in*, *acquiesce*, *yield*, or any of the others.

Comment: So they mean the exact same thing? I thought there might be a subtle difference.

Comment: The meaning is the same. The context is the only thing that's different. To *resign* a game of chess is a form of surrender, one specifically associated with that game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resign**
To give up a job or position by telling your employer that you are leaving.
In a game of chess, you resign when you cannot see any way to avoid being beaten.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resign

**Surrender**
To stop fighting and admit defeat
If you surrender to an experience or emotion, you stop trying to prevent or control it.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surrender

If the meaning is the same thing then "The enemy army resigned" would make as much sense as "The enemy army surrendered"

Surrendering in a war indicates that the victor has control over those who surrender.
The examples given in the dictionary for "resign" are mostly job related. The general idea is that the giving over of control is not as complete as when using "surrender".